# How to add a new ffmpeg codec id to libjitsi

Tags: java, ffmpeg, jitsi

I need to add support for AAC in my Java project that uses [libjitsi](https://github.com/jitsi/libjitsi) and I'm getting lost trying to figure out how the org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.codec.FFmpeg.class determines the codec id's that it has internally. For instance CODEC_ID_MP3 exists with the value of 86017; how is that int determined? I am not a C / C++ guy, so even though I looked through the [ffmpeg avcodec.h](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/avcodec_8h-source.html) file, I don't understand why the majority of enums don't have values associated; even the CODEC_ID_MP3 is blank there. So in summary how would I add CODEC_ID_AAC and CODEC_ID_AAC_LATM to my extension of the FFmpeg class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Boris from Jitsi, I created this snippit from [this header file](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavcodec/avcodec.h):

```
import org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.codec.FFmpeg;

public class MyFFmpeg extends FFmpeg {
    // 1 enums past mp3
    public static final int CODEC_ID_AAC = FFmpeg.CODEC_ID_MP3 + 1;
    // 48 enums past mp3
    public static final int CODEC_ID_AAC_LATM = FFmpeg.CODEC_ID_MP3 + 48;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // expect 86018 and 86065
        System.out.println("AAC: " + CODEC_ID_AAC + ' ' + CODEC_ID_AAC_LATM);
    }
}
```